# How to write jsonlogic.js rule that test an object against all objects in array (some)?

Tags: rule-engine, jsonlogic

I have data for [jsonlogic](http://jsonlogic.com/operations.html) rule:

```
{ "component": { "tableNumber": 102}, "refcomponents": [ { "tableNumber": 102}, {"tableNumber": 302} ] }
```

and i need to check if component's tableNumber is found in refcomponents array. Can this be done? If not what would be a workaround?

Following rule does not work because var is relative to items in refcomponent-array:

```
{ "some" : [ { "var": "refcomponents" }, { "==" : [{ "var": "component.tableNumber"} , { "var" : "tableNumber" }]}]}
```

so component.tableNumber is null and is never evaluated true.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like it was answered 3 years ago by the contributor to json-logic-js himself: https://github.com/jwadhams/json-logic-js/issues/17